# Set Horizontal Scrollbar Fix Position At The Bottom Of display Screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one div with horizontal scroll. And this div contains large data more than 1000 lines. So If I want to scroll horizontal first I need to scroll down to 10000 lines then horizontal scroll their. So my question is Can we fix the position of that horizontal scroll to window screen.

Comment: maybe you can set a max-height to your div. That way, a scrollbar is always visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by altering display property of div which is having horizontal scrollbar.

```
div.with-horizontal-scrollbar{
  display:table;
}
```